Resample on pandas api on spark
I'm trying to do resampling using pandas api for spark - (databricks runtime 15.4, spark 3.5.0)
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd
import pyspark.pandas as ps

dates = [
    datetime(2022, 5, 1, 4, 5, 6),
    datetime(2022, 5, 3),
    datetime(2022, 5, 3, 23, 59, 59),
    datetime(2022, 5, 4),
    pd.NaT,
    datetime(2022, 5, 4, 0, 0, 1),
    datetime(2022, 5, 11),
]
df = ps.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(dates), 2), index=pd.DatetimeIndex(dates), columns=["A", "B"])
print(df)


df.resample('2H').mean()

It should be simple task, but error i'm getting makes no sense:
File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/resample.py:724, in DataFrameResampler.__init__(self, psdf, resamplekey, rule, closed, label, agg_columns)
    715 def __init__(
    716     self,
    717     psdf: DataFrame,
   (...)
    722     agg_columns: List[Series] = [],
    723 ):
--> 724     super().__init__(
    725         psdf=psdf,
    726         resamplekey=resamplekey,
    727         rule=rule,
    728         closed=closed,
    729         label=label,
    730         agg_columns=agg_columns,
    731     )
File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/resample.py:102, in Resampler.__init__(self, psdf, resamplekey, rule, closed, label, agg_columns)
    100 self._offset = to_offset(rule)
    101 if self._offset.rule_code not in ["A-DEC", "M", "D", "H", "T", "S"]:
--> 102     raise ValueError("rule code {} is not supported".format(self._offset.rule_code))
    103 if not getattr(self._offset, "n") > 0:
    104     raise ValueError("rule offset must be positive")

The function works for rule codes days, months, but not for anything small.
I have tried running it on different runtime but got the same error.
There is no issue when i create to_offset
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
to_offset('2H')

